# Isn't this a good site for "What language is this?" questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Surprisingly, there seem to be no posts about this on meta yet. So, if you were active on scientific SE sites you have noticed every single one has a [identification](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) tag.

On stack-overflow, only specific programming questions are accepted so maybe people could ask here instead.

Comment: "...these questions aren’t educational in any way, because there’s no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Comment: Our version of identification questions tends to be more about "what design/architecture pattern is this?" than "what language is this?". I don't remember anyone ever asking us to identify a language, and I don't think it would be a good (or even interesting) question for the site.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't a good site for "What language is this?" questions.

These questions don't help "make the internet" better. They don't help future visitors to the site and they don't really help the asker. For most languages you have lots of clues that tell you what the language is, and if it's really that hard to work out then it must be a really obscure language that very few people use.

The fact that other sites have the [identification](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) tag doesn't mean that we should have one. On a personal level I don't that the other sites should have one either.